# commandLink with ui:repeat in composite component

Tags: jsf, el, commandlink

I am trying to use links in a composite component, my links are in a simple array and do not belong to any managed bean.

```
<composite:interface>        
    <composite:attribute name="links" required="true" />                
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>        
        <ui:param name="linksSplit" value="#{fn:split(cc.attrs.links, ',')}" />
        <ui:repeat var="link" value="#{linksSplit}" >                
            <h:commandLink value="#{option}" action="#{link}" />
        </ui:repeat>        
</composite:implementation>
```

I am getting the following error :
Identity '#{link}' does not reference a MethodExpression instance, returned type: java.lang.String

We are supposed to use String or bean methods in EL expression but I don't understand why we cannot evaluate a parameter which is a String (link in my case).

If I put a real String referenced in my faces-config, it works

```
<h:commandLink value="#{option}" action="#navigate" />
```

If you have an explanation or a workaround to get my link working, it would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying an EL expression in `<h:commandLink action>`, it's interpreted as a method expression returning a `String` (or `void` if you don't want to navigate). See also the [tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandLink.html):

> **Name** `action`
>
> **Type** `javax.el.MethodExpression` 
>   (signature must match `java.lang.Object action()`)
>
> **Description** `MethodExpression` representing the application action to invoke when this component is activated by the user. The expression must evaluate to a public method that takes no parameters, and returns an `Object` (the `toString()` of which is called to derive the logical outcome) which is passed to the `NavigationHandler` for this application.

Given the fact that you seem to want pure page-to-page navigation links, you're actually going in the wrong direction as to using `<h:commandLink>` for that. You should instead be using `<h:link>` for that. It generates SEO-friendly and bookmarkable GET links instead of a piece of JavaScript which submits a parent POST form.

```
<ui:repeat var="link" value="#{linksSplit}" >                
    <h:link value="#{option}" outcome="#{link}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one)

Note that this all has nothing to do with composite components. You'd have had exactly the same problem when using this in a normal page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed the h:link was the good solution. I spent so much time to be able to use it because I used an  old CustomNavigationHandler which sounds to interfere with the final link generation (no <a> tag generated), two issues solved in one.